# Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library. while using several Python modules (mayavi, spectral)

Tags: python, gtk, mayavi, spectral

I updated my MacBook to Mavericks, reinstalled Macports and all Python 2.7 modules I usually use. While running Python I get the following messages:

when importing mlab:

`from mayavi import lab`

`(process:1146): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.`

when running a mlab command such as mlab.mesh(), the display window opens, shows no content and freezes.

I don't get this message while importing spectral, but I get it when running `view_cube()` the display window showing the image cube, freezes but shows the data cube. It seems there is something wrong with Xterm, but I can't figure it out. How can I keep the display window from freezing and get rid of the Gtk-WARNING?

I checked locale and `locale -a`, but couldn't see anything unusual:
locale:

`locale`
 `LANG=`
 `LC_COLLATE="C"`
`LC_CTYPE="C"`
`LC_MESSAGES="C"`
`LC_MONETARY="C"`
`LC_NUMERIC="C"`
`LC_TIME="C"`
`LC_ALL=`

Comment: I got rid of the gtk-warnings using export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"... But the X11 window still freezes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using OS X Mavericks one has to use: `ipython --pylab=wx` instead of `ipython --pylab=osx` to avoid crashing the X11 window. I don't know why this works.