# "Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library. Using the fallback 'C' locale." on OS X

Tags: c, macos, gtk, locale

#### Background information:

I use Mac OSX Yosemite.

I've installed `gtk+` using `brew install gtk+` and fixed the errors using `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig`.

I've build my program using `make` but when I try to run it I get a warning like this:

```
(process:16182): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

### Problem: I cannot find any solutions for OS X for this particular problem.

#### What I've learnt so far:

1. In this thread ([Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library. while using several Python modules (mayavi, spectral)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366533/gtk-warning-locale-not-supported-by-c-library-while-using-several-python-mo)) they suggests using:

   > `ipython --pylab=wx` instead of `ipython --pylab=osx`

   but I've got no idea how python can be related to my problem (my program is written in C - the same applies to `gtk+` I guess)
2. You can find a lot of threads on this issue like this one: ([Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library. when starting apps from the commandline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359753/gtk-warning-locale-not-supported-by-c-library-when-starting-apps-from-th)) but they mainly refer to Linux and/or Ubuntu. 
   Most of the answers use a command like this sooner or later:

   ```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```

   But there is no `dpkg` on OS X.

Comment: what locale are you using? (environment variables LANG and LC_ALL (and siblings))

Comment: @PeterMiehle I've run `$ locale` and I got: `locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: so you answered your question by youself. (hint LC_ALL= empty is not a valid locale, so use "C" instead)

Comment: @PeterMiehle. You're right. Thank you. Should it be empty? From what I understand, it is quite comfortable that C assigns its own locale for the sake of the program. Why would I want to set LANG value globally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that the environment variable `LANG` is not set, because I've mixed settings for Polish and English in the *Language and Region* section in *System Preferences*.

Quoting [@KenThomases](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312143) who helped me a lot with this problem:

> There's not going to be any C library locale defined for the English language in Poland (i.e. en_PL.UTF-8). That's why Terminal is not setting LANG for you in your shells, even though you have "Set locale environment variables on startup" enabled.

You can read the in-depth solution here:
[Is it bad that LANG and LC_ALL are empty when running `locale -a` on OS X Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832012/is-it-bad-that-lang-and-lc-all-are-empty-when-running-locale-a-on-mac-osx-yos/30832995?noredirect=1#comment49822529_30832995)